# Java Image not showing up in Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I've made a JLabel with the Icon being an ImageIcon and it doesn't seem to be recognized.

When I add it to the project root it shows up in my IDE but it doesn't get added to the jar file when building.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class create {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    int y = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    public void CreateJFrame() {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Test");
        j.setLocation(rand.nextInt(x), rand.nextInt(y));
        j.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(rand.nextInt(x), rand.nextInt(y)));
        j.setResizable(false);
        j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        j.pack();

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("image.png"); // this file is in the resources folder and it is present in the jar file
        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        imgLabel.setIcon(img);
        j.getContentPane().add(imgLabel);

        j.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: `// this file is in the resources folder and it is present in the jar file` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. **Also:** This comes up so often that the comment is one of my 'copy/paste comments'. Please search in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this constructor: `new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(create.class.getResourceAsStream("image.png")))`.
You should use it because you cannot get files from the jar file, but you should use InputStream to read (and not write) from files in your jar file.
In addition to the this, make sure your image are in the jar file main directory and not in sub directories.

Comment: `"/image.png"` for an absolute path, for almost all those that use `package`.

Comment: Thanks, it works but, there's a typo in getResourceAsStream (you added an extra "s" in "Resource")